# How can i find bias of estimator for specific value?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, bias

I have $X_1,...,X_n~ Ber(p)$ with MLE estimator $\hat p$ which is equal to sample mean. I need to find bias of estimator $\hat p(1 - \hat p)$ for $p(1-p)$.

I presume $p(1-p)$ is variance of my RVs, so i must calculate $E[\hat p(1 - \hat p)]$ which is $E[\bar X_n - (\bar X_n)^2]$ which is 0 since $E[\bar X_n] = E[(\bar X_n)^2] = p$, and compare it to $p(1-p)$.

What am i doing wrong? I may be misinterpreting the task, since english isn't my first language, but since i tried all i can - i can't find proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected value of the square of sample mean is not $p$.
$$E[\bar X^2]=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n E[X_iX_j]$$

And, $E[X_iX_j]$ is $E[X_i]E[X_j]=p^2$ if $i\neq j$ and is equal to $E[X_i^2]=p$ if $i=j$.

Comment: How come, if for bernoulli distribution $E[\bar X_n] = P(X=1) * 1 + P(X=0) * 0$ and $E[(\bar X_n)^2] = E[g(\bar X_n)] = P(X=1) * g(1) + P(X=0) * g(0) = P(X=1) * 1^2 + P(X=0) * 0^2$  ?

Comment: $\bar X$ can be other values than $0$ or $1$.

Comment: I just realised that, thanks. What about "estimator X for Y" did i understand it right? If $E[(\bar X_n)^2] = p^2$ it seems that $\hat p(1- \hat p)$ is unbiased.

Comment: It's not $p^2$ nor $p$, follow the calculations I've started above.

Comment: My bad, doing exercises for about 12 hours now. Might be a bit tired

Comment: However - my concern is not about calculations, it's about understanding what am i asked to do. If i'll get wrong answer due to calculation errors - i won't be much disappointed) But i need to know what am i doing. Sorry for persistence.

Comment: Do you have anything left that you didn't understand?

Comment: I'm unsure of "estimator $\hat p(1 - \hat p)$ for $p(1-p)$". How can i find estimator for some value? I can understand if it means "find estimator for variance" or "find estimator for mean", but when i'm asked to find estimator for some value - i don't quite get it.

Comment: It's natural that you don't understand because finding "estimator for some value" is vague.